# Vector Subspaces and Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $E$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$ defined by the equations

$x_1 + 2x_2 + 5x_5 = 0$

$x_2 + 3x_3 = 0$

Calculate a basis of $E$ and expand it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$. Now we define a linear map $f: E \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5) = (x_1 + x_5, x_2 - x_3)$.

I am asked to find the matrix $M$ associated to $f$ with respect to the basis of $E$ obtained in the last question and the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have found that a basis for $E$ is $\{(-5,0,0,0,1), (0,0,0,1,0), (6,-3,1,0,0)\}$, but now i don't know how to find that matrix $M$, can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since:

- $f(-5,0,0,0,1)=(-4,0)$;
- $f(0,0,0,1,0)=(0,0)$;
- $f(6,-3,1,0,0)=(6,-4)$,

the matrix that you're after is$$\begin{bmatrix}-4&0&6\\0&0&-4\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yes but this matrix cannot have as inputs vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$

Comment: Of course not! Its inputs are the triplets $(a,b,c)$ that you get when you write a vector $v\in E$ as$$a(−5,0,0,0,1)+b(0,0,0,1,0)+c(6,-3,1,0,0).$$

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. So if I were to compute $f(-5,0,0,0,1)$ i would multiply that matrix by $(1,0,0)$?

Comment: Sure! And you would get $(-4,0)$ then. It makes sense, right?!

Comment: Of course! Now a lot of sense! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.